# update statement giving uknown column error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update 1 column based on if the categories_id is equal to 90 in a second table but getting an unknown column error.

Here is my sql:

```
UPDATE products SET qty='20' 
WHERE products.products_id = products_to_categories.products_id AND products_to_categories.categories_id = '90'
```

The error I am getting is

Unknown column 'products_to_categories.products_id' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, you have to introduce table names with `from` (or `update` or `delete`) statements.  You may mean:

```
UPDATE products
    SET qty = '20' 
    WHERE exists (select 1
                  from products_to_categories ptc
                  where ptc.products_id = products.products_id AND
                        ptc.categories_id = '90'
                 );
```

Another way to do this is with a join:

```
UPDATE products p join
       products_to_categories ptc
       on  ptc.products_id = products.products_id AND
           ptc.categories_id = '90'
    SET p.qty = '20';
```

This works better if there is more than one match.

Comment: Isn't the first condition inside the inner WHERE clause redundant?

Comment: Do you mean that the way he write his sql query is suitable only for updating from one table alone?

Comment: @Itay . . . Fixed.  I guess I was choosing between `=` and `exists` and got did both.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine two tables in an UPDATE command like that. Use a subquery.

```
UPDATE products SET qty='20' 
WHERE products.products_id IN (SELECT `ptc`.`products_id`
                               FROM   `products_to_categories` `ptc`
                               WHERE  `ptc`.categories_id = '90')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the table in your join statement, `products_to_categories.products_id` can't be found unless the table is joined.

```
UPDATE products a
       INNER JOIN products_to_categories b
             ON a.products_id = b.products_id
SET    a.qty = '20' 
WHERE  b.categories_id = '90'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql's [multiple table syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE products
JOIN products_to_categories
  ON products.products_id = products_to_categories.products_id
  AND products_to_categories.categories_id = '90'
SET qty='20'
```

See this query syntax checked on [SQLFddile](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff3e46).

Comment: @gordon me neither :) I'm going to try a fiddle

Comment: . . As a note, I didn't downvote you.  I don't downvote anymore.

Comment: @GordonLinoff OK, got it sorted. I was thinking a out the multi table delete and got tangled. Thx for paying attention.

Comment: @GordonLinoff me neither downvote, unless its dangerous code, then i leave a comment as to why. If wrong I suggest a correction or whatever. Down voting is mean. Btw, I noticed you're an SQL machine! Mongo respect sheriff Bart.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE products p, products_to_categories pc
SET p.qty='20' 
WHERE p.products_id = pc.products_id AND pc.categories_id = '90'
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd62d)**